# Problem statement : Prevent Deletion of Loan Application if Applicant exists. Loan Application -> parent obj and Applicant -> child. Is trigger right?

Tags: trigger, before-trigger

```
Trigger LoanApplicationTrigger on Loan_Application (before delete) {
   Set<Id> LoanIdSet = new Set<Id>();
   For(Loan_Application loanApp : Trigger.old ) {
       LoanIdSet.add(loanApp .id);
   }

   List<Applicant> ApplicantList = [select id from Applicant__c where LoanId In =: LoanIdSet ] ; 

   For( Loan_Application loanApp : Trigger.old) {
      If( ApplicantList.contains(loanApp.id) {
         LoanApp.addError (“Applicant exists on loan application. You cannot delete this Loan application “);

      }

   }
}
```

Comment: Why not write a unit test with some meaningful asserts and try? Sorry for not providing an answer instead, but I have faced such questions so often myself, and if I asked StackExchange each time, they kicked me out a long time ago.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're ignoring the actual field / object api names. The idea here seems correct. There is one issue with your code with line,

> If( ApplicantList.contains(loanApp.id) {

ApplicationList here will be list of Application__c so you can't directly check if the list has any particular id(loadApp.Id). To fix this you would have to iterate the ApplicationList again to populate a Set of Ids having parent Loan Application Ids.
The final code will then look something like.

```
trigger LoanApplicationTrigger on Loan_Application__c(before delete){
    Application__c[] applications = [SELECT Id, Loan_Application__c FROM Application__c WHERE Loan_Application__c ID IN: Trigger.oldMap.keySet() ];
    Set<Id> loanApplicationWithApplications = new Set<Id>();
    for(Application__c application: applications){
        loanApplicationWithApplications.add(application.Loan_Application__c);
    }
    for(Loan_Application__c loanApplication: (Loan_Application__c[])Trigger.old){
        if(loanApplicationWithApplications.contains(loanApplication.Id)){
            loanApplication.addError('You can\'t delete a Loan Application having applications');
        }
    }
}
```

Even better you can use a JOIN to know the Loan Applications that does have linked Application records

```
trigger LoanApplicationTrigger on Loan_Application__c(before delete){
    Loan_Application__c[] loanApplicationsWithApplications = [SELECT Id FROM Loan_Application__c WHERE Id ID IN (SELECT Loan_Application__c FROM Application__c)].keySet();
    for(Loan_Application__c loanApplication: (Loan_Application__c[])Trigger.old){
        if(loanApplicationWithApplications.contains(loanApplication.Id)){
            loanApplication.addError('You can\'t delete a Loan Application having applications');
        }
    }
}
```

This will let platform hanlde most the filtering instead of you iterating each of the record to find out if it has any related Application record.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a trigger for this. You can simply specify the option to prevent deletion of the parent object on the field itself.

[image: Prohibit Cascade Deletion]

On the field properties, simply check:

> Don't allow deletion of the lookup record that's part of a lookup relationship.

And the database will enforce this for you.